# Get an element inside a specific element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php code which build a html code like that :

```
echo '<button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in afficher_itk" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>';

echo' <div class="itk" id="'.str_replace(' ','',$systeme_culture['nom_plante']).'">
    <table class="table">
        <th><td>
            <tr colspan="2">
                   <label>Nom : </label>
                   <input class="nom_itk" id="nom_itk" value="test">
             </td</tr>
        </th>
     </table>
 </div>';
```

This code is dynamically generated, and I can have more than 1 code like that.

As it can have several things like that, I want to target the rights element when I run my javascript.

When I click on the button, I want to add a content inside the corresponding `input`. Not the first one, not the last but only in the matching code.

I have something like that in js :

```
$(".afficher_itk").click(function(){
    $itk = $(this).closest(".itk"); //Here, I tried to select the closest itk class which correspond to the first div
    $itk.find(".nom_itk").val("test"); //Here I tried to search the input child
}
```

But this code doesn't work. Can someone know how can I do this please ?

Comment: Hi are you looking for something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/nw7vb2dk/

Answer (score 0):

Dont select the closest `itk`, closest traverse upwards in DOM Tree. Instead use `.next` to select the next `itk` from the current element:

```
$(".afficher_itk").click(function(){
    $itk = $(this).next(".itk"); 
    $itk.find(".nom_itk").val("test");
});
```

Comment: Nope, sorry, it doesn't work. But I found how I can do. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I found how I can be. Instead of select the `closest`, I get the `td` parent with the function `parents()`. After that, I can use the find function.

```
$itk = $(this).parents('td');
$itk.find('.nom_itk').val("lison");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

It works if the element is DOM Object

```
jQuery("html").on("click",".afficher_itk", function(){
    $itk = $(this).next(".itk"); 
    $itk.find(".nom_itk").val("test");
});
```